# Pandas- Cumulative sum on date time and start over every day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume that I have this dataframe.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {"Date_Time": ["2018-08-14 02:00:00", "2018-08-14 01:00:00", "2018-08-14 00:00:00", "2018-08-13 23:00:00", "2018-08-13 22:00:00", "2018-08-13 21:00:00", "2018-08-13 20:00:00"], 
        "Date": ["2018-08-14", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-14", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-13", "2018-08-13"], 
        "Duration":[3, 0, 0, 10, 2, 20, 1], 
        "value":[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 23, 22],
        "Remark":["e", "o", "k", "x", "c", "z", "a"]
       }
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df

    Date_Time                 Date    Duration  value   Remark
0   2018-08-14 02:00:00     2018-08-14    3       4     e
1   2018-08-14 01:00:00     2018-08-14    0       3     o
2   2018-08-14 00:00:00     2018-08-14    0       2     k
3   2018-08-13 23:00:00     2018-08-13    10      1     x
4   2018-08-13 22:00:00     2018-08-13    2       0     c
5   2018-08-13 21:00:00     2018-08-13    20      23    z
6   2018-08-13 20:00:00     2018-08-13    1       22    a
```

I'd like to make the cumulative summation for each day. However, I want my day to start at 22:00 each day. So, the "value" column is the reference to hour of that day.

Or I can do

```
    from datetime import timedelta
    two_hours = pd.Timedelta(hours=2)
    df["dummy_date"] = df["Date_Time"] + two_hours
    df

    Date_Time               Date    Duration    value   Remark      dummy_date
0   2018-08-14 02:00:00     2018-08-14    3     4     e         2018-08-14 04:00:00
1   2018-08-14 01:00:00     2018-08-14    0     3     o         2018-08-14 03:00:00
2   2018-08-14 00:00:00     2018-08-14    0     2     k         2018-08-14 02:00:00
3   2018-08-13 23:00:00     2018-08-13    10    1     x         2018-08-14 01:00:00
4   2018-08-13 22:00:00     2018-08-13    2     0     c         2018-08-14 00:00:00
5   2018-08-13 21:00:00     2018-08-13    20    23    z         2018-08-13 23:00:00
6   2018-08-13 20:00:00     2018-08-13    1     22    a         2018-08-13 22:00:00
```

If that helps you to see how I count a day as shown in "dummy_date".

However, what I really want is I want to do cumulative summation on "Duration" column based on daily basis. So, the cumsum will start over every day when "value" is 0 or at mid-night of the "dummy_date" column. Below is the desired out put that I'm looking to achieve.

```
        Date_Time               Date      Duration  value   Remark  cum_sum     dummy_date       
    0   2018-08-14 02:00:00     2018-08-14     3        4         e     15  2018-08-14 04:00:00
    1   2018-08-14 01:00:00     2018-08-14     0        3         o     12  2018-08-14 03:00:00
    2   2018-08-14 00:00:00     2018-08-14     0        2         k     12  2018-08-14 02:00:00
    3   2018-08-13 23:00:00     2018-08-13    10        1         x     12  2018-08-14 01:00:00
    4   2018-08-13 22:00:00     2018-08-13     2        0         c      2  2018-08-14 00:00:00
    5   2018-08-13 21:00:00     2018-08-13    20       23         z     21  2018-08-13 23:00:00
    6   2018-08-13 20:00:00     2018-08-13     1       22         a      1  2018-08-13 22:00:00
```

cum_sum of the first row is the sum of duration from the forth row upward, 2 + 10 + 0 + 0 + 3 = 15.

The second row is 2 + 10 + 0 + 0 = 12.

The third row is 2 + 10 + 0 = 12.

The third row is 2 + 10 = 12.

The forth row is 2  = 2.

The fifth row is the sum of the sixth row and the fifth row, 1 + 20 = 21 because the "value" is 23 which is considered to be another day or it can be seen from "dummy_date".

The sixth row is the 1.

My attempt was to use the rolling from pandas. However, I don't know how to set it to start over when it begins a new day.

```
df["cum_sum"] = df["Duration"].rolling(24, min_periods=1).sum()
df
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe need change order by `iloc[::-1]` or [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), then `groupby` by `dates` from `dummy_date` column or `Series` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df["cum_sum"] = df["Duration"].iloc[::-1].groupby(df['dummy_date'].dt.date).cumsum()
print (df)
            Date_Time        Date  Duration  value Remark          dummy_date  \
0 2018-08-14 02:00:00  2018-08-14         3      4      e 2018-08-14 04:00:00   
1 2018-08-14 01:00:00  2018-08-14         0      3      o 2018-08-14 03:00:00   
2 2018-08-14 00:00:00  2018-08-14         0      2      k 2018-08-14 02:00:00   
3 2018-08-13 23:00:00  2018-08-13        10      1      x 2018-08-14 01:00:00   
4 2018-08-13 22:00:00  2018-08-13         2      0      c 2018-08-14 00:00:00   
5 2018-08-13 21:00:00  2018-08-13        20     23      z 2018-08-13 23:00:00   
6 2018-08-13 20:00:00  2018-08-13         1     22      a 2018-08-13 22:00:00   

   cum_sum  
0       15  
1       12  
2       12  
3       12  
4        2  
5       21  
6        1
```

If dont need `dummy_date` in output:

```
two_hours = pd.Timedelta(hours=2)
dates = (df["Date_Time"] + two_hours).dt.date
df["cum_sum"] = df["Duration"].iloc[::-1].groupby(dates).cumsum()
print (df)
            Date_Time        Date  Duration  value Remark  cum_sum
0 2018-08-14 02:00:00  2018-08-14         3      4      e       15
1 2018-08-14 01:00:00  2018-08-14         0      3      o       12
2 2018-08-14 00:00:00  2018-08-14         0      2      k       12
3 2018-08-13 23:00:00  2018-08-13        10      1      x       12
4 2018-08-13 22:00:00  2018-08-13         2      0      c        2
5 2018-08-13 21:00:00  2018-08-13        20     23      z       21
6 2018-08-13 20:00:00  2018-08-13         1     22      a        1
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values('Date_Time')
two_hours = pd.Timedelta(hours=2)
dates = (df["Date_Time"] + two_hours).dt.date
df["cum_sum"] = df["Duration"].groupby(dates).cumsum()
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
            Date_Time        Date  Duration  value Remark  cum_sum
0 2018-08-14 02:00:00  2018-08-14         3      4      e       15
1 2018-08-14 01:00:00  2018-08-14         0      3      o       12
2 2018-08-14 00:00:00  2018-08-14         0      2      k       12
3 2018-08-13 23:00:00  2018-08-13        10      1      x       12
4 2018-08-13 22:00:00  2018-08-13         2      0      c        2
5 2018-08-13 21:00:00  2018-08-13        20     23      z       21
6 2018-08-13 20:00:00  2018-08-13         1     22      a        1
```

Comment: I'm always so happy when searching for a question and Jezrael has provided an answer.